# extracting downsampled timeseries from a normalised csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from a CSV that looks like this (sample data here: http://www.speedyshare.com/9A2zf/download/sample.csv):

```
                          event    name          user  count  amount  commission
2011-05-23 00:00:00  2011-07-22  normal  reading_arts      2      26         0.0
2011-05-23 00:00:00  2011-07-23  normal  reading_arts     14     182         0.0
2011-05-24 00:00:00  2011-07-22  normal  reading_arts      4      52         0.0
2011-05-24 00:00:00  2011-07-22  normal  reading_arts      3      39         0.0
2011-05-26 00:00:00  2011-07-23  normal  reading_arts      2      30         0.0
2011-05-26 00:00:00  2011-07-23  normal  reading_arts      5      75         0.0
2011-05-26 00:00:00  2011-07-22  normal  reading_arts      1      13         0.0
2011-05-27 15:39:28  2011-07-23  normal       hickies     16     208       -10.4
2011-06-01 00:00:00  2011-07-23  normal  reading_arts      2      30         0.0
2011-06-02 00:00:00  2011-07-23  normal  reading_arts     17     221         0.0
```

..that I created with:

```
data = read_csv('2011.csv', 
                names=('event', 'user', 'count', 'amount', 'commission'), 
                parse_dates=True)
```

'event', while it looks like a date, is actually just an identifier for a particular event.

You'll note there are duplicate entries in the DateTimeIndex, eg: 2011-05-23 00:00:00.

What I eventually want is a set of 3 timeseries (for each of count, amount and commission) for each user for each event, downsampled to weekly buckets by summing up. I'd also like to create similar timeseries for each event, which would simply be a sum of the per-user-per-event time series.

How would I do that?

Comment: Would be useful to provide a sample CSV excerpt to allow people to easily re-create your dataframe to play around with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit - try this code:

Note - I took the csv and added a header to each row.  The row 1 column headers I added are:

```
time    event   name    user    count   amount  commission
```

Try running this and let me know if it's still not what you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame.from_csv('sample.csv')

resamp = df.groupby(['event','user']).resample('W', how='sum')
```

Comment: Sample data here: http://www.speedyshare.com/9A2zf/download/sample.csv

Where you have "#calculate the week for each row", I'd ideally want to use Pandas's resampling, how would I do that?

Comment: Check out the edits above and let me know if that is more what you're looking for.